# User Profile Personal Fields Privacy - Where/Which field is that info stored?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, user-profile, spuser, security-trimming

How is stored personal fields (for example birthday) visibility (Everyone/Only Me) per user profile in SPO/O365?
OnPrem is something like DefaultPrivacy and UserOverridePrivacy but on SPO I can't find which field are those values stored. Tried via graph, pnp powershell, nothing so far...

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta#properties

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/jj163873(v=office.15)

Any idea or tip?